# Incompatible Types java generics issue

Tags: java, generics, incompatibletypeerror

I cannot really understand this `Incompatible types` compilation error.

```
interface Request {}

interface Response {}

class Foo {

   <RQ extends Request, RS extends Response> RS foo(RQ rq) {
      // This doesn't compile: Incompatible types error
      return foo3(foo2(rq));

      /* This compiles fine */ 
      // RS rs = foo2(rq);
      // return foo3(rs);
   }

   <RS extends Response, RQ extends Request> RS foo2(RQ rq) {
      return null;
   }

   <RS extends Response> RS foo3(RS rs) {
      return rs;
   }
```

The curious thing for me is that the code compiles fine if in the method `foo` I replace this:

```
return foo3(foo2(rq));
```

by:

```
RS rs = foo2(rq);
return foo3(rs);
```

For sure I'm missing something, but I still don't get why.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because in the case of using

```
RS rs = foo2(rq);
return foo3(rs);
```

the compiler know which concrete type (`RS`) to use for the specialization of `foo2`. You are telling it specifically which type you want.

In the case of `foo3(foo2(rq));` the compiler cannot deduce that. So you just get the less specialized type `Response` as result of `foo2`, which doesn't work with `foo3`.

Note that this automatic deduction is necessary because the type parameters `RS` are *independent* for every method. Nobody guarantees that they refer to the same type in the whole class. If you want them to be the same in the whole class, make the class itself generic, not the methods.

Answer (score 3):

`foo2`'s and `foo3`'s `RS` type parameters are not related. If you want to force them to be the same, put the type parameter in the class level.

```
class Foo <RQ extends Request, RS extends Response> {

   RS foo(RQ rq) {
      return foo3(foo2(rq));
   }

   RS foo2(RQ rq) {
      return null;
   }

   RS foo3(RS rs) {
      return rs;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the wake up call